# Select numbers with commas

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select all rows, which are numbers and commas, nothing else. 
For example these varchars should be returned by select:

```
1
1,2
1,2,3
```

Have you any idea how to do it?

Comment: Some kind of regular expression LIKE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

```
where col not like '%[^,0-9]%'
```

If you want to prevent two commas from being in a row:

```
where col not like '%[^,0-9]%' and
      col not like '%,,%'
```

I feel the need to add that storing numbers in comma-delimited lists is a really bad idea.